# How to checkout most recent revision of the current branch in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Let's say I updated to an older revision in my working directory to do some tests, and now I want to switch back to the most recent revision.
I thought `tip` would do the trick but no, this tag is the most recent revision on the repo, not only in my current branch.

Is there any tag to update to that means "most recent commit of your current branch"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hg update` with no argument will do the job. When you don't specify any revision, the *update* command will automatically update to the most recent commit of the current branch. That was easy after all.

> If no changeset is specified, update to the tip of the current named
>   branch and move the active bookmark

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#update